# How to get previous 2 and 3 months end date in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to get the previous 2 and 3 month end date. In the below code, I am able to get the last month end date which is 2021-01-31, but I also need to get 2020-12-31 and 2020-11-30.

Any advices are greatly appreciated.

```
today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
lastMonth = first - dt.timedelta(days=1)
date1=lastMonth.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
date1
```

Out[90]: '2021-01-31'

Comment: Are actually using pandas here or just the native python `datetime` library?

Comment: "*Any advices are greatly appreciated*" but you didn't bother to cast a single vote to none of the 4 answers offered?

Comment: How to cast a vote ?

Comment: Figured out how to cast a vote. Just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
prev2month = lastMonth - pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=1)

prev3month = lastMonth - pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=2)
```

More usage information of `offset` (e.g. `MonthEnd`, `MonthBegin`) can be found in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics).

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way for doing this without needing to deal with the varying number of days in each month is to simply repeat the process N times, where N is the number of months back you want:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
temp_date = today.replace(day=1)
for _ in range(3):
    previous_month = temp_date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(previous_month.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    temp_date = previous_month.replace(day=1)
```

outputs

```sh
2021-01-31
2020-12-31
2020-11-30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the calendar package:

```
import calendar
calendar.monthrange(2020, 2)[1] # gives you the last day of Feb 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're definitely using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) then you can make use of `date_range`, eg:

```
pd.date_range('today', periods=4, freq='-1M', normalize=True)
```

That'll give you:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-02-28', '2021-01-31', '2020-12-31', '2020-11-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='-1M')
```

Ignore the first element and use as needed...

Alternatively:

```
dr = pd.date_range(end='today', periods=3, freq='M', normalize=True)[::-1]
```

Which gives you:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-31', '2020-12-31', '2020-11-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='-1M')
```

Then if you want strings you can use `dr.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` which'll give you `Index(['2021-01-31', '2020-12-31', '2020-11-30'], dtype='object')`